# Camera image of the target

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am trying to develop an AR app for Android using Vuforia SDK. And i am trying to capture the camera image of only the target that is detected, not the whole camera screen, but only the target on the screen.

I can manage to get the whole screen with the way they described on "How can I access the camera image" section, but not the detected target image.

anyone has an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty standard procedure (unwarp operation), and an implementation with Vuforia is available on the Vuforia website, Knowledge Base Articles section:

[Camera Target Patch](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/camera-target-patch) (look specifically at the `copyCameraPatchToTexture` function)